# Каким членом предложения является слово "подумать"?

Tags: синтаксис

... губернатор предложил городской Думе подумать о его перестройке.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово **"подумать"** в данном примере является дополнением.

Инфинитив при спрягаемом глаголе является дополнением, а не основной частью сказуемого, если его действие относится к второстепенному члену.  **(Я просил его уехать),** а не к подлежащему **(Я решил уехать).**

То же и в вашем примере: Предложил губернатор, а подумает дума.